# Integrating LineChartView in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart, ios-charts

I am using the iOS-charts library to integrate [LineChartView](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and I have to create below chart :

[image]

So far I have achieved this :

[image]

I am facing three issues here :

- Feb and Jun month text is missing in `xAxis`.
- Have to add Left and right space in the chart.
- Remove "Description Label" text visible in the chart.

**Is it possible to add small mark above months as shown in the image for indicating months in `xAxis` ?**

Implemented code :

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
let unitsSold = [50.0, 25.0, 50.0, 75.0, 100.0, 75.0]

setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
```

and the `setChart` method:

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: dataPoints[i] as AnyObject)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: nil)
    chartDataSet.circleRadius = 5
    chartDataSet.circleHoleRadius = 2
    chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false

    let chartData = LineChartData(dataSets: [chartDataSet])


    lineChartView.data = chartData

    lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: months)
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    lineChartView.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true

    lineChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    lineChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false

    lineChartView.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    lineChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    lineChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    lineChartView.legend.enabled = false
}
```

Please help if anyone has worked on charts in swift.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** To avoid crowd `Chart` shows limited data in graph axis by zooming user can see the entire data

**2)** For left and Right spacing: Give left and right constraints from interface builder

**3)** To hide description you can use below code

```
lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = " "
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Your 3rd answer worked. Thank you for that. I didn't get your first answer - you mean feb and jun text is bigger that's why it is not visible. For left and right space what I am saying is `Jan` is starting from the beginning of the chart. In the above image you can see some space before `Jan` and after `Jun`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I did this to solve it:

```
ineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: months)
ineChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(months.count, force: true)
```

Hope it helps.